# What does 'state' mean in this context? (Discussion about storing JWTs in cookies)

Tags: rest, session, cookies, state, jwt

From [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage/):

> Cookies, when used with the HttpOnly cookie flag, are not accessible through JavaScript, and are immune to XSS. You can also set the Secure cookie flag to guarantee the cookie is only sent over HTTPS. This is one of the main reasons that cookies have been leveraged in the past to store tokens or session data. **Modern developers are hesitant to use cookies because they traditionally required state to be stored on the server, thus breaking RESTful best practices**. Cookies as a storage mechanism do not require state to be stored on the server if you are storing a JWT in the cookie. This is because the JWT encapsulates everything the server needs to serve the request.

As I read this, I understand a cookie with 'state' to be a cookie which contains data concerning an application/session... so therefore a cookie containing a JWT would have state, no?

Also, why would storing a JWT in a cookie to authenticate API calls break RESTful best practices?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regard to:

> I understand a cookie with 'state' to be a cookie which contains data concerning an application/session... so therefore a cookie containing a JWT would have state, no?

The "traditional usage" of cookies and the server having state was (generally) where a cookie contained a session ID, and the server held in memory the details of what this session was (the state, held on the server). This meant that a request sent to the server with the session ID cookie attached, would need to use the server's state (what was in the session) to figure out which operation to perform or how to perform it. In this example the cookie didn't itself usually contain any state as it was just a session ID which did not tend to change between requests.

I believe your confusion stems from the fact that the JWT will change depending on user actions - having some state stored within it - but this is okay. The break in RESTful practices comes from the server having state stored in it rather than the client sending what information is required to act on the request.

As the quote from Stormpath is describing, storing JWT in a cookie does not break the stateless paradigm of REST as the server has to decode the JWT on each request and use the data contained within it - almost as another header on the request, albeit secured somewhat.

Admittedly, you could just store another session ID or something similar in the JWT that the server could be using statefully, although in general a JWT tends to contain a client identifier or something similar, which is trusted due to the signature of the JWT, and perform any operations based on this - **all the information the server requires to act on the request is part of the request, rather than some of it being state stored in the server**.

Comment: Got it, a re-read of the article makes a lot more sense in this context!  Thanks